# Using parameter with cursor in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SP that gets date as parameter, I'm trying to use the varable inside the query but SQL doesn't seems to "see" it

```
alter procedure PipeReport
  @1 as DATE
as
begin

DECLARE @SqlCD NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @Thickness NVARCHAR(100)

--DECLARE @SlpCode INT

SET @SqlCD = N'
/* SELECT FROM  [dbo].[ORDR]  T2 */
 

  declare   @1 as DATE

SELECT C0.DocNum ,OI.ItemName'

/* הנתונים שעליהם רצה הלולאה */
DECLARE SizeList CURSOR FOR

       SELECT 

            cast( R1.U_Thickness as nvarchar)--+''/''

       FROM
              RDR1 R1
              INNER JOIN ORDR R ON R1.DocEntry = R.DocEntry
       WHERE
              R.U_ImpDate=@1
                            and 
              R1.[U_Shelf] is null
                       and 
R1.[LineStatus]=N'O'
       GROUP BY
              U_Thickness
                       
       HAVING 
       R1.U_Thickness IS NOT NULL 
       AND 
       R1.U_Thickness > 0 



OPEN SizeList


FETCH NEXT FROM SizeList INTO @Thickness


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
       SET @Thickness = ( SELECT TOP 1 U_Thickness FROM RDR1 WHERE U_Thickness = @Thickness)
       SET @SqlCD = @SqlCD + ',SUM( CASE WHEN T0.U_Thickness = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),@Thickness) + N' THEN T0.Quantity END) AS N'' ' + @Thickness + N''' '
      
       FETCH NEXT FROM SizeList INTO @Thickness
END

SET @SqlCD = @SqlCD + N' FROM     
RDR1 T0   
INNER JOIN ORDR C0 ON C0.DocEntry = T0.DocEntry 
INNER JOIN OITM OI ON t0.ItemCode = OI.ItemCode
where 
C0.U_ImpDate = @1
AND 
T0.[U_Thickness] <>0 
and 
T0.[U_Shelf] is null
and 
OI.U_Group=400 
and 
T0.[LineStatus]=N''O''
AND C0.DocNum IS NOT NULL


Group BY ROLLUP(C0.DocNum),OI.ItemName
ORDER BY 1 DESC; '

CLOSE SizeList
DEALLOCATE SizeList

EXEC(@SqlCD)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

A variable or parameter is visible only within the scope in which it is declared.  The parameter `@1` is visible in the body of your procedure, but not in the dynamic script your procedure is generating and executing.  Even though the dynamic script is declaring a variable with the same name and type, the value of the `@1` parameter is not automatically passed to it.

If you want to pass it, use `EXEC sp_executesql <your query>` instead of `EXEC(<your query>)` to run your dynamic SQL, because the former allows you to use proper parametrisation.  In your specific case, what you need to do is this:

1. Remove the `declare   @1 as DATE` line from the dynamic SQL.
2. Replace the `EXEC(@SqlCD)` line with this:

   ```
   EXEC sp_executesql @SqlCD, N'@1 DATE', @1;
   ```